# What are the differences between HBase version 1.X and 2.X

Tags: hbase

What are the significant differences between the 1.X versions of HBase and 2.X?

The official [changelog](https://apache.org/dist/hbase/2.0.1/CHANGES.md) just contains thousands of closed JIRA tickets. The [release notes](https://apache.org/dist/hbase/2.0.1/RELEASENOTES.md) are slightly more readable, but not by much.

Can someone please provide a more readable explanation?

Comment: have a look at this.

https://www.slideshare.net/enissoz/meet-hbase-20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The significant changes between 1.x and 2.x versions are:

- Hbase 2.x works only on Java 8+
- Older 1.x client APIs are deprecated. APIs are made better in 2.x
- No managed connections in 2.x
- Changes in Filter and Co-processor

2.x versions are aimed at achieving below points:

- Heavy update operations to be better in 2.x than in 1.x
- Make read cache faster as a whole
- Make use of available RAM
- Reduce temporary garbage for reading
- Reduce GC in writing and improve throughput
- Many off-heaping changes
- Changes in memstore like reduce flush to disk, memory compaction, etc
- Async client
- Better native backup-restore solution

There would be other changes too on co-processor metrics api, replication changes, etc.

Comment: Great answer , took  me a long time to dig up and confirm your comment. Was  a great help appreciate it.